# How to insert margin note just left side of all page in my persian document?

Tags: marginnote, persian

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\newcommand{\mymarginnote}[1]{%
  \marginpar{\colorbox{yellow}{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{%
  \setstretch{0.5}\textcolor{red}{\scriptsize{#1}}}}}}

 \usepackage{xepersian}
\begin{document}
\begin{persian}
ریاضیدانان بزرگ جهان تلاش فراوانی در جهت پیشبرد اهداف علوم مختلف انجام داده اند.
\mymarginnote{نظریه اعداد از مباحث ریاضی است.}
\newpage
ریاضیدانان بزرگ جهان تلاش فراوانی در جهت پیشبرد اهداف علوم مختلف انجام داده اند.
\mymarginnote{نظریه اعداد از مباحث ریاضی است.}
\end{persian}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should clarify somewhere that XeTeX is needed to compile your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your issue isn't related to the use of the `xepersian` package, the following code should solve your problem.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{everyshi}
\usepackage{changepage}
  \strictpagecheck
\makeatletter
\EveryShipout{\aftergroup\marginpar@left@fix}
\def\marginpar@left@fix{%
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
    \aftergroup\reversemarginpar
  \else
    \aftergroup\normalmarginpar
  \fi}
\newcommand{\mymarginnote}[1]{%
  \marginpar{\hspace{4em}\colorbox{yellow}{\parbox{1in}{%
    \setstretch{0.5}\textcolor{red}{\scriptsize #1}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
  \reversemarginpar
\else
  \normalmarginpar
\fi
\mymarginnote{Note 1}
\lipsum[1-2]
\newpage
\mymarginnote{Note 2}
\lipsum[3-5]
\newpage
\mymarginnote{Note 3}
\lipsum[6-8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Ruben.Thank you.i ised your code but in xepersian it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @user50054 Can you describe shortly what exactly does not work?